# Python append element with for ... in leads to infinite loop but not with for ... range

Tags: python

I have a list that I want to append the same elements to itself.

`myList = [1,2,3]`

Doing this with for...range is ok:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    myList.append(myList[i])

print(myList) # [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

But with for...in will cause infinite loop:

```
for i in myList:
    myList.append(i)

# infinite loop
```

Why is that? My guess is `in range(len(myList))` is only evaluated once, but `in myList` is re-evaluated every single iteration? Is this just how python works?

Comment: Yes of course, that's how python works, for debugging purposes, you can even put a print statement after the append line and check what happens to the list, and you are literally inserting a list into itself, which also can be done like `myList.extend(myList)`

Comment: No, `mylist` is only evaluated once, but the list object itself is changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both evaluated once. The problem is that `myList` is a mutable object, and list iterators don't make a copy of the list, which means the iterator will always have a new value to yield as long as you keep appending items inside the loop.

`range(len(myList))` evaluates to `range(3)`. This range object does not know about the list, and when it changes size, that does not change the range (nor could it, as range objects are immutable in Python).

If you wish to loop over a list you're planning on mutating, a better option would be to make a copy of it:

```
for item in myList[:]:
    myList.append(item)
```

The copy is not mutated, and so it will only run a finite number of times.

As Ghost Ops mentioned, the best way to append the elements of a list to itself is `myList.extend(myList)`.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in myList` will repeat for every element in `myList`. As you keep on appending elements to `myList` with each iteration (and the loop is evaluated with each iteration), it will repeat forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the loop will last until every `item in mylist` is reviewed. But `mylist` is not ending because the loop is always appending some items In it. When you use the `len()` method, it is always the fixed value so that's why the `len()` method loop is not infinite. But when you use `item in mylist`, the item in the `mylist` gets appended every time so that's why the loop lasts forever.